# Query on Polarization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, polarization

Describe the state of polarization represented by
(here w = omega and TT = pi)

a) $E_x = E\sin(kz - \omega t)\,\& \,E_y = E\cos(kz - \omega t)$

b) $E_x = E\cos(kz - \omega t) \,\&\, E_y = E\cos(kz - \omega t + \pi/4) $

c) $E_x = E\sin(kz - \omega t) \,\&\, E_y = E\sin(kz - \omega t)$

Comment: You'll have to tell us where you are having trouble.  We won't do your homework for you, but we will help clarify trouble spots.

Comment: See also: [this question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) which offers help on asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By plotting $|\mathbf{E}(t)|$ in Mathematica, it's visually clear that the first is circular, the second is elliptical, and the third is linear.

```
k = 1;
z = 0;
w = 1;
R1 = Norm[{Sin[k z - w t], Cos[k z - w t]}];
R2 = Norm[{Cos[k z - w t], Cos[k z - w t + \[Pi]/4]}];
R3 = Norm[{Sin[k z - w t], Sin[k z - w t]}];
Plot[{R1, R2, R3}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

As user `garyp` mentioned, in the future please try to provide more info when asking, take the time to attempt the problem yourself, and make it clear which conceptual issues you understand and which you are having trouble with.

Comment: -1 for doing somebodies homework for them without explaining any conceptual information.  Yeah they didn't ask for any concept but the only right thing to do would have been to provide the concept stuff anyways without answering.  Your answer provides positive reinforcement for asking homework questions on this site so maybe my downvote here will provide the negative reenforcement to counterbalance.

Comment: @BrandonEnright: Agreed that providing an answer may be an incentive for future bad questions clogging up the site, although I suggested to him at the end of my answer that he really ought to do more legwork before asking in the future. The fact that this question has -3 ratings and has been up for nearly 12 hours without being closed for being off-topic suggests that a more aggressive pruning of bad questions by the mods is also needed. Anyways, in the future I'll try to use comments and flags for this sort of thing, rather than answers.

Comment: Downvote reversed.  Please think about the quality of the site :-)